# How to set a conditional breakpoint for C++ strings in VS2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to set a conditional breakpoint for my debug but VS keeps returning me this error:

[image]

How can it be so if the operator != is defined for strings?

The variable error is `std::string`

Comment: *How can it be so if the operator != is defined for strings?* -- It "can be so" if the debugger does not have the capability to do this.  The debugger is not a C++ compiler -- it is a third-party (or in this case same-party) tool.  If the functionality doesn't exist, then raise this issue with the Microsoft engineers.  Basically this is a tooling issue, and if conditional breakpoints for overloaded operators doesn't exist, then the best you can do is to propose this as an enhancement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many workarounds you can do, for example a much better way of writing your condition is this:

```
!errors.empty()
```

You also have `size()` that you can compare against 0, `c_str()` that returns a C string which you can test the first element against `\0`, etc etc.

As to the reason why your line doesn't work is that most likely the conditional debugger can't resolve the overloaded operator. Perhaps checking against a non-implicitly built `string` (ie, `error != string{}`) would work better, or using a newer VS version, but really you can see how wasteful that is instead of just simply checking the `empty()` function result.

Comment: What you say is true enough, but how is any of this going to help the OP set a conditional breakpoint?  I can tell you from first-hand experience that the VS debugger can only do this for primitive types.

Comment: Far be it for me to judge what your first-hand experience is worth, but [this](https://i.imgur.com/e2wotGp.png) works just fine for me.

Comment: Interesting, I take it all back!  (I may have been on VS 2017 at the time.)

Comment: Just took another look.  I am using a [method of a] custom class, and I get 'expression has side-effects and cannot be evaluated'.  But it doesn't, so it looks like I need to declare it `constexpr` (which I will try - I should have done that anyway).  And a subdued +1 for you :)

Comment: Yeah, `empty()` was also rejected because of that rule, which is silly, but `size()` works as expected.

Comment: Hmmm, strange.  I just found the same thing with my custom class - declaring (my) `empty()` as `constexpr` didn't help.  It calls another function (which I've now also marked `constexpr`), so maybe the debugger can't cope.  But I can, so that's good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily adding something like this to your code might do it:

```
const auto s = string_i_want_to_test_to_see_if_its_empty.c_str ();
```

and then for the conditional breakpoint, the expression would be:

```
s [0] != 0;
```

Put that breakpoint on the line immediately after the one added.  Hopefully, in a Debug build, it won't get optimised out.  If it does, I'm sure you'll think of a way round it.